# convert markdown to json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, converters, markdown

I have a markdown file imported in a node module like this through a webpack loader

`import mardownFile from './markdownfile.md'`

this file is a text book with chapters separated by a ## / h2 tag

now, I'm looking for a way to convert this into a json object with each h2 tag (or other possible wrapper) in separate chapter chunks to use with a react page component with the page content as props.children. More details on what I'm trying to solve

I have this in my markdown.md file

```
#Title
##Chapter 1
text text
text
##Chapter 2
text
etc
##Chapter 3
more text
image
```

I would like to read this markdown and convert it to an object, something like this...

```
var aText = {
pages: [
{
 "title": "Chapter 1.",
 "text": "text",
},
{
"title": "Chapter 2.",
"text": "text",
},
{
"title": "Chapter 3.",
"text": "text",
"img": "cat-stevens.png",
}
]}
```

Then in a javascript react component render a Page component like this

`<Page page={aText.pages[0]} />`

I'm on a mac osx computer but this is personal web client project, I was trying to parse this in a standard browser, i'm using Chrome, What's the best approach to accomplish this, any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example? I'm not sure to understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Are you on linux, mac, or windows? I can update my answer with more detail for your situation.

Answer (score 14):

You can not import md file, because import for only on javascript files.
You need use some markdown parser or write your own. For example [markdown-it](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/#MarkdownIt.parse):

```
var MarkdownIt = require('markdown-it');
var md = new MarkdownIt();
var result = md.parse('# markdown-it rulezz!');
console.log(result);
```

You will get:

```
[Token {
  type: 'heading_open',
  tag: 'h1',
  attrs: null,
  map: [0, 1],
  nesting: 1,
  level: 0,
  children: null,
  content: '',
  markup: '#',
  info: '',
  meta: null,
  block: true,
  hidden: false
},
  Token {
  type: 'inline',
  tag: '',
  attrs: null,
  map: [0, 1],
  nesting: 0,
  level: 1,
  children: [[Object]],
  content: 'markdown-it rulezz!',
  markup: '',
  info: '',
  meta: null,
  block: true,
  hidden: false
},
  Token {
  type: 'heading_close',
  tag: 'h1',
  attrs: null,
  map: null,
  nesting: -1,
  level: 0,
  children: null,
  content: '',
  markup: '#',
  info: '',
  meta: null,
  block: true,
  hidden: false
}]
```

Comment: Thanks this would work as a basis, From this I could loop through the result   looking for the chapters to push them into separate objects.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Any Markdown parser which outputs a list or tokens (or any other low level date structure) would work.

Comment: @galkin markdown-it looks interesting, however, I can't tell if markdown-it can re-assemble Markdown from their tokenized format. It appears their [Renderer](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/#Renderer) can only consume tokenzied Markdown and return HTML. Do you know more about markdown-it's full capabilities? Their documentation does not explicitly state what markdown-it is capable of, or I missed that section.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [markdown-to-json library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-json).

```
npm install -g markdown-to-json
```

Given a file called `lottery.md` I go to the directory in my terminal and type:

```
m2j lottery.md
```

This outputs the json on the screen.

If you're using a [bash based terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) you can pipe that output into a file like this.

```
m2j lottery.md >> lottery.json
```

Which will create a json file called `lottery.json` in the same folder as your markdown.

For additional help you can use:

```
m2j -h
```

Comment: I was looking for a web client, react based solution to this cli version

Answer (score 2):

For a more recent solution, check out unifiedjs's [mdast](https://github.com/syntax-tree/mdast). There's a huge ecosystem of tools for converting from *many* different flavors of markdown to json/html/jsx/etc.

You'd use [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark) to convert markdown to "markdown abstract syntax tree".

This is their example for converting to html:

```js
import {unified} from 'unified'
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
import remarkRehype from 'remark-rehype'
import rehypeSanitize from 'rehype-sanitize'
import rehypeStringify from 'rehype-stringify'

main()

async function main() {
  const file = await unified()
    .use(remarkParse)
    .use(remarkRehype)
    .use(rehypeSanitize)
    .use(rehypeStringify)

  console.log(String(file))
}
```

To keep json, just get rid of the plugins from `remarkParse` on.

Comment: To keep json, just get rid of the plugins from remarkParse on.  ?????

Answer (score 1):

For my first search on this I've found the [jsonmark](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonmark) package that is kinda what you have requested but it creates an object with order and contents which is not necessary and is hard to modify its code as it is based on regexp.

I agree with galkin's response that using a markdown parser's tokens should get you what you want.

Here is my example of how to create a json object based on markdown. My goal was to have a json array with elements that have a head and body, head is the h1 and body is all that goes beneath it. In the example I'm using [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) as the markdown parser. (I'm Running it on nodejs as reading from file is not quite possible from file otherwise.)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var marked = require('./marked.min.js');
var finally = [];
var heading = '';
var lexbody = [];

var loadmd = function(file){
  var markdown = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
  jsonraw = marked.lexer(markdown);
  finally = [];
  heading = '';
  lexbody = [];
  jsonraw.forEach(getThem);
  return finally;
}
var getThem = function(item, index){
  if (item.type == "heading" && item.depth == 1){
    if (heading == ''){
      heading = item.text;
    } else {
      lexbody['links']=jsonraw.links;
      finally.push(
        {
          "heading": heading,
          "body": marked.parser(lexbody)
        }
      );
      heading = item.text;
      lexbody = [];
    }
  } else {
    lexbody.push(item);
  }
  // don't leave out the last element
  if (index == jsonraw.length-1){
    lexbody['links']=jsonraw.links;
    finally.push(
      {
        "heading": heading,
        "body": marked.parser(lexbody)
      }
    );
  }
}
```