# markdown list-styled tree to json

Tags: json, markdown

How to parse markdown list-styled tree to json
eg: in `.md`

```
tree1
  - tree2(http://xxxx)
  - tree2(http://xxxx)
    - tree3(http://xxxx)
another-tree1
```

what I want is to be parsed like json:

```
[{
  name: 'tree1',
  link: '',
  children: [{...}]
}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert markdown to json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442058/convert-markdown-to-json-object)

Comment: I realize the structure is different in this question than in the duplicate linked above, but the answer will be the same: Use a Markdown parser which outputs a token list, loop through that token list and extract the data you need to build your data structure.

Comment: @Waylan actually, they are not the same, i've published a lib to convert to json. see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[md-list-tree-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-list-tree-parser)

> parse list-styled markdown tree to json