# How to Convert Markdown to JSON?

Tags: python, node.js, json, markdown

I need help with something.I need to convert the Markdown file to json format, but I don't know how to do this.I did a Google search, "markdown to json" but the tools I used didn't work for me.Is there someone who has experienced this before?

PS: I can use Nodejs and python for this.But I used the nodejs and python modules related to this did not work.

example Markdown

````
```{python}
from __future__ import division
from deltasigma import *
```

### 5th-order modulator: NTF *with* zeros optimization

This time we enable the zeros optimization, setting `opt=1` when calling synthesizeNTF(), then replot the NTF as above.

* 0 -> not optimized,
* 1 -> optimized,
* 2 -> optimized with at least one zero at band-center,
* 3 -> optimized zeros (with optimizer)
* 4 -> same as 3, but with at least one zero at band-center
* [z] -> zero locations in complex form
````

I would like this or similar json output

```
{
    code:
    header :
    content :
}
```

In fact, as long as code and other content blogs are separated, there is no problem.

In addition to the above, I can even write my own converter with nodejs, but it can take a very long time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In which programming language, do you want to achieve this ?

Comment: Nodejs or python doesn't matter.
But I used the nodejs and python modules related to this did not work.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442372/7158344 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it doesn't work.Because my Markdown file is a little big. I need a nice json printout.

Comment: There isn't a sensible semantic for mapping Markdown to JSON. You'll have to be a lot more specific about what kind of JSON you're looking for, and what you are using it for. This question is not answerable in its current condition.

Comment: Well, then I've updated the question.

Comment: It appears that the "markdown-to-json" tool is simply a way to represent JSON data as plain text. In other words, the Markdown document must follow a specific subset of Markdown to work properly (which might explain your errors). Seems to me YAML would be a more fully developed solution to the same problem. Have you considered YAML instead of Markdown? If that doesn't fit your needs, why not?  I would also suggest updating your question to better convey what you actually want to accomplish. Provide a sample Markdown document and a sample JSON output (with data included) from the sample input.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You mentioned you Google'd this, so I'm sure you saw this, but for a working example of this in python, check out: https://github.com/njvack/markdown-to-json

Beyond that, I recommend reading the `README` for the project on some things you're going to run into. Ultimately, they're not the same *type* of format, so the conversion isn't reversible without guess work. Notice how all of the packages are a variety of responses. They're inventing a JSON key-value response structure to make things semi understandable.

If existing tools don't do what you need, try checking out what they're doing, and change it to your needs.

Comment: I've seen this tool, but I get an error while running, so I didn't see a result
markdown_to_json.markdown_to_json.ContentError: Error at line 20: Can't mix lists and other content . Thank you for your advice

Comment: The point I'm trying to make here, is that there are a *lot* of tools that do this, as you well know from Google. Start with a simple markdown file, and see if the issue is with your markdown and its ability to convert it, or if it's the tool being broken. You can either debug the tool, or pick a different one. Since you seem to know what you want as a response format, the biggest thing I recommend is just looking at their code, and rewriting something tailored to your needs, as I doubt you're going to find any perfect solutions here.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a nice solution. Truth be told, I've tried this before.
But I don't want to waste time.
Because even if I have enough time, I can even write something like that myself.

Comment: I hope I've helped friend. Good luck with your goal! If this gave you what you needed, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: You've really helped, but if I accept this as an answer, someone else may not be. So if I don't wait until tonight and get a better comment, I'll confirm the answer. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

There is a very straightforward approach incase you are working on rasa.

```
import rasa_nlu
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data

input_training_file_md_file = "nlu_data.md"


output_json_file = 'nlu_data.json'

with open(output_json_file,'w') as f:
    f.write(load_data(input_training_file_md_file).as_json())
#done
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Tried this solution to no avail: `Unknown data format for file <my_file.md>` with proper markdown inside. Also need to be mentioned `rasa_nlu` has lots of dependencies.